# How can I include necessary libraries with VB.NET project?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, windows-installer, windows-10, visual-studio-2005

I am reworking old VB6 apps into VB.NET with Visual Studio 2005 and when i tried to install them on Windows 10 I got following errors:

[image: adodb vb.net windows 10 error]

[image: msdatasrc vb.net windows 10 error]

How can I include the missing libraries and carry them with the project?
Or can i somehow make a VB.NET installer with Visual Studio 2005 and it will take all dependencies with it?

Comment: Your VS version is very old, that does get to be a liability when you try to create programs for a new OS.  These are PIAs, they are installed on your machine in c:\windows\assembly so the compiler does not think it needs to copy them.  But not on the Win10 machine, kaboom.  A workaround is to set their Copy Local property to True, so they do get copied into the build directory, and have your installer put them in the GAC.

Comment: @HansPassant I am on Windows XP using VS 2005, not Windows 10. I need to make installer that will include all dependencies and be able to install the final product on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It went well. I created new Setup project by using this tutorial [vs 2005 setup project tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12548/Visual-Studio-Windows-Application-Setup-Project) .

I added all the files that resided in the bin folder of my development project, plus I added **adodb.dll** by using the **"Add Assembly"** dialog window, right click on the setup project **"Application Folder**" node.

I also added **msdatasrc.dll** which is like backward compatibility library for MS Office for Windows XP. You can find download link here [office xp support files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328912/microsoft-office-xp-primary-interop-assemblies-pias-are-available-for)

Once you these files, you can create shortucts which will open the main *.exe file when double clicked. Shortcuts for the desktop and for menu, can be added on the nodes **User's Desktop** and **User's Menu**